# How to create an http server on android that a desktop can access (vice-versa) using NanoHTTPD

Tags: android, proxy, android-wifi, file-transfer, nanohttpd

Using an available WiFi IP (i.e. 192.xxx.x.x, using post 8080), I'd like to create a http server in android that can connect and can be accessed by a desktop so that I can transfer files to the android device.

Update:
I'm currently trying out NanoHTTPD but I can't seem to make the sample HelloWorld run on android device..

I changed the hello world code and made it extend activity instead and created an object [nanohttpd](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/).

I modified up to specifying what port to be used but upon further debugging, I found out that the server socket has no getInetAddress at all. I thought NanoHTTPD no longer needs further config...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, as it turns out, NanoHTTPD does the trick but I made some adjustments...

1. Check if the device is connected.

   I used samples from [manage wifi](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/htc/articles/75491.aspx) and [wifi network management](http://windev-us.net/WXUS_WEB/pdf/LSTArticle.pdf) to create a WiFi Manager that detects all available WiFi, returns list of ScanResults, connected Scan Result and fetched the IP address.
2. Made the NanoHttpd as a class with singleton instance.

   From the resulting connected ScanResult of WiFi Manager, I [got the IP Address](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/07/getting-ip-address-of-the-device-in-android/) and passed it and a port number to the nanohttpd instance.

   NanoHttpd nanoInstance = new Nanohttpd();
   String[] args = null;
   args[0] = the ip address;
   args[1](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/htc/articles/75491.aspx) = 8080; // or 8081.. etc
   nanoInstance.main(args);
3. After that I finally reached the response page. =]

Comment: I can also transfer from desktop to device through NanoHttpd using its file-upload-test.htm

Comment: can you please provide me some sample snippet for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an embeddable http server: http://tjws.sourceforge.net/

Note: most mobile devices are behind [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (both on Wifi and cell networks), where inbound connections are not possible. This means you can not initiate connection to them from internet.